# Multiplying BigInt

Tags: java, bigint

```
int SIZE = 512;        
p = new BigInteger(SIZE, 15, new Random());
q = new BigInteger(SIZE, 15, new Random());
r = new BigInteger(SIZE, 15, new Random());

n = p.multiply(q);
temp1=n;
n = n.multiply(r);
   if (temp1.multiply(r)!=n) System.out.println("test");
```

My code here prints `test` when it shouldn't. Why?

Comment: multiply is BigInt's. Didn't overload or anything

Comment: you're just multiplying in the if condition, but not assigning the result to anything. You sure you want to do that? Also use equals to check for equality of BigIntegers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `equals` to compare Object equality.

`!=` or `==` compare references.

```
BigInteger b0 = new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("0");
System.out.println(b0 != b1);
System.out.println(!b0.equals(b1));
```

**Output**

```
true
false
```

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc `temp1=n;` is an assignment, not a check for equality.

Comment: Yes, but I asked if the assignment is correct. Or do I need to use a method for that, too.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc no, you don't need a special method to assign a value to a reference. Well not in this case at least.

Answer (score 2):

According to this implementation:

```
public BigInteger multiply(BigInteger val) {
    if (val.signum == 0 || signum == 0)
        return ZERO;

    int[] result = multiplyToLen(mag, mag.length,
                                 val.mag, val.mag.length, null);
    result = trustedStripLeadingZeroInts(result);
    return new BigInteger(result, signum == val.signum ? 1 : -1);
}
```

`temp1.multiply(r)` returns a **new** `BigInteger` object, which will have a different address than `n`.
Use `!temp1.multiply(r).equals(n)`.